# Javascript - check the position on screen after the scroll has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script where I scroll down to an element on click or page load, but I need trigger scrolling down, when the image is loaded, because I have problem with scrolling until the page is loaded. Now I need to solve the problem that when the page is loaded already and if it is on the position that it is supposed to be, that it doesn't scroll again. How can I check if the page has already scrolled to that position:

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: magazineDetailOffset
});

$('#cover-image').load(function() {
  console.log($(".magazine-detail").offset().top - 80);
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: magazineDetailOffset
  });
});
```

So, basically I need to make a check if the element is already scrolled to the top and only if it is not then do the scroll animation again.

```
$('#cover-image').load(function() {
  if (theElementIsNotScrolledToTop) {
    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: magazineDetailOffset
    });
  }
});
```

But not sure how to do that?
I have tried with with checking `$(document).scrollTop()` but that always gives me `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the image is exactly at the top (not below or above), you can set `theElementIsNotScrolledToTop` as so:

```
theElementIsNotScrolledToTop = $('#cover-image').offset().top !== $(window).scrollTop()
```

but if you are even a pixel off, it will still fire, so you may want to add some logic to find the threshold you are looking for, hope that helps!

Comment: ```$(window).scrollTop()``` is also giving ```0``` at the time load function executes, since there is no scrolling at the time when load function is executed. So I can't compare it like that.

Comment: @Leff Have you tried delaying the execution using setTimeout?

Comment: No, and that is not desired in this scenario